# How to add some methods in Motodev studio without typing it out

Tags: android, motodev-studio

For example, if I want to add this method:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    //some code I add later...
    }
```

is there a way to add it without typing it all?
I know that when I want the onClick method, I implement it in the class, then it shows an error, I hover my mouse over and click add unimplemeted methods, and it's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Eclipse, right-click over the class, choose Source > Override/Implement Methods from the context menu, and check off the method(s) you want to add to the class.

Answer (score 0):

I know another simple way to quickly add such methods in eclipse. I think you know about intellisense - write some characters then press `Ctrl + Space`. The available options will be shown in a dropdown list if there are multiple option. For single option the word will be just written.

Ok now for your case `onActivityResult`. Type few characters like `onActivity` then trigger intellisense. You'll see a list of few options. From there select `onActivityResult` by pressing up and down key and press enter. You'll see the whole method is written down.

I do that all the time. No mouse click, just type few characters.